# How to copy a List<T> to a multidimensional array with a for-loop?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, list-template

I'm working with 3D coordinates. I have them all saved into a List, but to keep working with them, I need to have them into a multidimensional array (float[,]).

My list looks like this:

```
<Coordinates> hp_List = new List<Coordinates>();

public class Coordinates
{
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
    public float z { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the following code:

```
int R = hp_List.Count();
float[,] hp_array = new float[R, 3];
for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < hp_List.Count; j++)
    {
        hp_array[i, 0] = hp_List[j].x;
        hp_array[i, 1] = hp_List[j].y;
        hp_array[i, 2] = hp_List[j].z;
    }
}
```

and I also tried this other way:

```
for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
{
    foreach (Coordinates hp_position in hp_List)
    {
        hp_array[i, 0] = hp_position.x;
        hp_array[i, 1] = hp_position.y;
        hp_array[i, 2] = hp_position.z;
    }
}
```

I expected the following output:

```
589,5  -75,4  238,4
46,2   173,2  70,9
45,7   173,4  70,9
160,9  75,5   75,4
160    76     75,2
156,1  83,9   73,6
```

My actual output is

```
156,1
83,9
73,6
156,1
83,9
73,6
156,1
83,9
73,6
156,1
83,9
73,6
156,1
83,9
73,6
156,1
83,9
73,6
```

which as you can see is the last element of my list.

I'm not sure where my mistake is.

Comment: Output of what? Please post the code that generates the output.

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should `hp_array[i, 0] = hp_List[i].x;` and get rid of the nested for.

Answer (score 4):

Both loops are iterating through all the elements in the list

```
for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < hp_List.Count; j++)
    {
    ////
    }
}
```

Don't forget that `R == hp_List.Count`. That is why all the rows in the array contain the last three elements of the list.

Try discarding the inner loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
{         
    hp_array[i, 0] = hp_List[i].x;
    hp_array[i, 1] = hp_List[i].y;
    hp_array[i, 2] = hp_List[i].z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Coordinates> hp_List = new List<Coordinates>
        {
            new Coordinates
            {
                 x = 1,
                 y = 2,
                 z = 3
            },
            new Coordinates
            {
                 x = 4,
                 y = 5,
                 z = 6
            }
        };

        int R = hp_List.Count();
        float[,,] hp_array = new float[R, 1, 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                hp_array[i, j, 0] = hp_List[j].x;
                hp_array[i, j, 1] = hp_List[j].y;
                hp_array[i, j, 2] = hp_List[j].z;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("X Y Z"));
        for (int i =  0; i< R; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", hp_array[i, 0, 0], hp_array[i, 0, 1], hp_array[i, 0, 2]));
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Out Put

### X Y Z

1 2 3

4 5 6